# Backtesting trading algos using simulated price instead of historical prices

Tags: algorithmic-trading

I don't have any real experience in trading. I have a question in my mind for which I can't convince myself.

Why do we need real history price data to do back-testing?

In my mind, real data is only a realization of 'the' process. If there's a good fitting model, isn't it better to use it for back-tests? By this means, we will be able to see how it is going on in other scenarios because real data may not include those bad scenarios.

Thanks

Comment: We don’t have a process that would fit well enough. The stochastic processes used also often rule out the profitability of such strategies beforehand e.g. by assuming constant expected returns.

Comment: For risk analysis yes, the models can be helpful to generate test data. But to test if the trading method makes money, real data is the only way.

Comment: isn't the jump-diffusion model enough? I have seen several papers that show it's a good fit for real-world returns.